# Remote debugging of Docker containers using IntelliJ

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, remote-debugging, intellij-plugin

I have a number of Docker containers (10) each running a Java service that makes up my system.  To create these containers I use a couple of `docker-compose` files.  Using the Docker Integration plugin for IntelliJ, I can now spool up these services to my remote server using the Docker-compose option (the images used are built outside of IntelliJ, using Gradle).  Here are the steps I have done to achieve this:

1. I have added a Docker server using the `Docker Machine` option to connect to the remote Docker daemon (message says `Connection Successful`).
2. I have added a new Docker Compose configuration, using the server, specifying my compose files, and the services I want to start.

Now that I have the system controlled through IntelliJ, I have been trying to figure out how to attach the remote debugger to each of these services so that IntelliJ will hit my breakpoints.

Will I need to add the JVM args (`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`) to each service (container) and add the usual remote debug configuration for each service?  Do I need to use a different address for each service?  If so, how do I add these args?  Surely with the Docker Integration plugin, there is an easier way to do this.

IntelliJ Idea v2018.1.5 (Community Edition)

Docker Integration v181.5087.20

Comment: Please see https://ngeor.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/debugging-docker-with-intellij-idea/.

Comment: The link has moved here https://ngeor.com/2017/03/26/debugging-docker-with-intellij-idea.html